# Swiftmailer parse error EsmtpTransport

Tags: php, jquery, swiftmailer

I am trying to setup swiftmailer on a website I am building. I have an HTML contact form that uses javascript to verify the email address which then uses a post ajax call with jquery to my PHP file to send the email. If successful PHP will return 'succ' to jquery to display the proper HTML

In the browser I get the error response from my javascript (please try after some time) and this error in my log file when I submit my request from the site:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/mycpanel/public_html/mywebsite.com/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php on line 211
```

Which refers to this code:

```
 /**
     * Returns the IP used to connect to the destination.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSourceIp()
    {
        return $this->params['sourceIp'] ?? null;
    }
```

This is my Javascript on the page which verifies the email (checks for characters etc). Makes the ajax call to my mymail.php file that has my PHP code and waits for a response. If the response is 'succ' it will display success HTML. Else it will display error.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#myID').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var em = form.find('#Email');
            var x = true;

            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if(em.val().trim() == '' || !regex.test(em.val())) {
              em.css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
              $('.myId-msg .myId-valid').text('Please enter valid e-mail...').addClass('error-message');
              $('.myId-msg').addClass("show-block-error").removeClass("show-block-valid");
              x = false;
            } else {
              em.css('border-bottom','1px solid #eaeaea');
              em.parent().find('.err-msg').remove();
            }
            if(x==false) {
              return false;
            }else{


            $.ajax({
                url: "example.com/mymail.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize()            
              }).done(function(res) 
{if(res == 'succ') {
                  $('.myId-msg .notify-valid').text('Your information has been sent successfully...').addClass('error-message');
                  $(".myId-msg").addClass("show-block-valid").removeClass("show-block-error");
                  form[0].reset();
                } else {
                    $('.myId-msg').addClass("show-block-error").removeClass("show-block-valid");
                    $('.myId-msg .myId-valid').text('Please try again.').addClass('error-message');
                }
              });
            }
        });
```

and this is my PHP

```
<?php
    // import the required stuffs
    require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
  //set post to emaila
    $emaila = $_POST[('email')];

    // Create the mail transport configuration. I am using shared hosting which gave me my server information for SMTP
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('server.domain.com', 465, 'ssl')
      ->setUsername('email@example.com')
      ->setPassword('my_secret_pw')
      ;   
    // Create the mailer
    $mailer= Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('email@example.com' => 'My Name'))
      ->setTo(array($emaila))
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
      ;

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    if ($mailer->send($message)) {

        echo 'succ';

    } 

    ?>
```

How can I resolve this error when it says the syntax error is coming from a library file I downloaded from the git repo?

Comment: could this be because my server is currently running php55 instead of 7

Comment: Have you checked by removing single '?' from the statement?

Comment: PHP version might be causing this issue. As they have mentioned that Swift Mailer is a component based mailing solution for PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because i was using php5.5. I could not upgrade to php7 because of legacy CMS systems using depreciated mysql extensions.

using an old version of swiftmailer fixed this issue.

Comment: Glad your issue is now fixed.